# Calling async method and TaskScheduler in async/await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, .net-4.5

Consider the following code

```
async Task<int> foo()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return 42; 
}

...
// OPTION 1

Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(foo,
            CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);

t.Wait();


...
// OPTION 2
Task t = foo();
t.Wait()
```

The questions

1. what is the substantial difference between two calling options?
2. In option 1. Suppose I override the default TaskScheduler. For await in foo method - which TaskScheduler will be used? Will it use the default or the one passed in parameter to father task?

Comment: Option 2 never even starts a thread?

Comment: @Henk It starts and executes

Comment: @Henk I beleive at least the Task.Delay part will be executed on a tread pool thread.

Comment: A Delay() does not need (to occupy) a Thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, though, the "option 1" will create a *new Task* that wraps the call to `foo()`, effectively making a `Task<Task<int>>`.  When you call `.Wait()` on it, it will not wait for the inner task to complete, since the inner task will return nearly immediately (as soon as the `Task.Delay`) is hit.

As to your question about using a non-default `TaskScheduler`, in general, it won't change the behavior, except for the fact that it may block until the custom scheduler starts the task.  Without more information about the scheduler in question, it's impossible to know exactly what would happen.

The second option, however, will block until the delay is completed, as it will start the task, and block until after the delay is completed.

Comment: you say the await will use custom scheduler used for foo creation?

Comment: @Boris No, but `Task.Factory.StartNew` will use your scheduler, which may or may not actually start the `Task` :)

Comment: Sorry,... I am completely confused :( As I understand If I have async method which uses await inside, compiler  effectively creates the task chain consisting of method parts as separate tasks. Now.. How can I ensure each of these tasks are scheduled using my custom task scheduler?

Comment: This is the link which explains it - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx

Comment: @Boris You can't specify a scheduler for the tasks internal within an await call... There is no mechanism for that.  You can only schedule the "top level" one using a TaskFactory

Comment: That's kinda dissapointing. I would expect that if one can override SynchronizationContext he would be able to override the TaskScheduler also... In any case a lot of thank for the answer

Comment: @Boris You can make your own Sync context, and install it, and await will use it - but there is no mechanism for changing the schedulers.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would like to limit the parallelism level to one worker thread only, but still enjoy prettyness of await without cludging the code with structures like in OPTION 1.

Comment: @Boris A single await chain will only use one tp thread, since it's really one set of async operations run after each other...

Comment: This is not the behaviour I observed, the task may continue in entirely different thread after await, No to talk about ContinueWith (unless executesynchrnopusly is set but it does not answer my requirements). Do you have link confirming the point? The problem is that all my tasks using shared data structures. And I hoped to avoid synchronization routines.

Comment: @Boris It may be a different thread, but there should only ever be one at a time...